# ASP .NET Core 2.1 get variables from appsettings.json without Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my appsettings.json. It is located in a class library that does not have a startup.cs. I'm wondering if its possible to get the variables out from there to be used locally?

```
{
  "AccountsAddress": "http://localhost:55260/api/Accounts/",
  "ApplicationUsersAddress": "http://localhost:55260/api/ApplicationUsers/"
}

public static class Manager
{
    public static IConfiguration AppSetting { get; }
    static Manager()
    {
        AppSetting = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
    }
}
```

[image]

This is the structure of my library

Comment: If you are writing a library, why don't you just let the application handle it. Hard coding it into your library will just be a huge inconvenience to whoever uses your library.

Comment: Because the will change between environments and I'm thinking changing a json file will be easier.

Comment: Ah, absolutely, it is. But why do you insist your library must have it's own instead of having your application supply those? Why don't your classes just get injected what they need and the application will provide the config?

Comment: My thinking is that I'm going to use this class library for multiple applications. I don't want to have to write extra code in my application when I can just get my class library to read from its own appsettings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
  "AccountsAddress": "http://localhost:55260/api/Accounts/",
  "ApplicationUsersAddress": "http://localhost:55260/api/ApplicationUsers/",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Create An myConfig.cs file and paste following code.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
static class ConfigurationManager
{
    public static IConfiguration AppSetting { get; }
    static ConfigurationManager()
    {
        AppSetting = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("YouAppSettingFile.json")
                .Build();
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like :

```
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["value_Key"];
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I'm using your solution and I'm getting a null. Do I need to do anything to adapt it to my appsettings?

Comment: It's work for me. can you show your code? maybe your appsettings file in incorrect.

Comment: What does your appsettings look like?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my app structure

Comment: @JianYA make a sample test project and try.

Comment: I realized whats going on. Its taking the appsettings.json from another linked project for some reason. Is it possible to specific the appsettings.json of this project?

Comment: @JianYA If it is possible, I dont know. make a new post for that.